# Spring MVC and Ajax: error 404 when calling URL that uses a Token

Tags: ajax, spring, passwords, uri, token

I'm implementing a "forgot password" feature. I'm using Spring MVC and Ajax but I'm having some trouble when I want to call the spring controller method through Ajax, using a token url. The code I have is something like this:

**Spring Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/resetPassword/{token}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String doResetPassword(@PathVariable("token") String tokenID, 
        @RequestParam String newPassword, HttpServletRequest request) { ... }
```

The *token* is the unique id that randomly generates when the user requests a password reset and gets a temporary link via email that redirects him/her to the Reset Password page.

**Ajax function**

```
         $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "./resetPassword/" + token,
              data: "newPassword=" + password,    
              async: false,
              success: function(response){               
                 ...
```

When I make the Ajax call, I get a **404 Page Not Found** error.

**NOTE:** The URL format works. I already have other Ajax functions using the `./`
The controller method that shows the Reset Password form is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/resetPassword/{token}")
public String showResetPasswordPage(Model model, @PathVariable("token") String token){
    model.addAttribute("token", token);
    return "account/resetPassword";
}
```

The issue appears with the previous request method, when the user actually clicks the button (after entering new password).

Comment: so how are you getting the token from your JSP model into your javascript variable?

Comment: I'm using this:  `var path = window.location.pathname;  var token = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED.** I had to remove part of the Ajax url. Now the Spring controller method is launched and the password reset is working fine now.

**Before:**

```
 url: "./resetPassword/" + token,
```

**After:**

```
 url: "./" + token,
```

Thank you guys for all your comments and help.

Comment: Makes sense. Since you were already on ./resetPassword, submitting to ./resetPassword would have actually submitted to ./resetPassword/resetPassword/token

Comment: Exactly! Though I finally realized about that after seeing the console log :S

Answer (score 1):

Simplify. Break it out and verify each piece separately, then put them together.

- Try hitting it with a browser instead of ajax first to figure out if your problem is in the ajax or in the request mapping. You could try a rest plugin for your browser to make it easier to POST, or just hard code a form with `action="resetPassword/1234-asdf-1234-asdf` and an input box named newPassword.
- Then, have a look at the token and see if there are characters that need to be URL encoded.
- Make sure that the token is not empty (i.e. it is populated correctly from the JSP model to the javascript variable.
- Then hardcode the URL in the ajax to make sure that much works. (I suspect you could remove the `./` in front of resetPassword)
- ???
- Profit.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
Try encoding the URL:

```
url: "./resetPassword/" + encodeURIComponent(token),
```

Comment: Actually that works just fine. I already have other Ajax functions that use similar URLs but this is the first one with dynamic parameters.

Comment: Ok so the problem is related to your generated token. try encoding the url using encodeURIComponent() http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the first dot, and make the path absolute, if you do not require a relative path;

```
   $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "/absolutepath/resetPassword/" + token,
              data: "newPassword=" + password,    
              async: false,
              success: function(response){
```

Which IDE are you using ? Many, like IntelliJ, support a rest service tool to test these webservices from your IDE.

Comment: I already solved the issue but since you ask, I use eclipse. Didn't know about IntelliJ but I'll have it in mind.